# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in Laravel Controller

Tags: arrays, laravel, view, controller, php-7.2

I have two request sample and incomplete sample, I get the complete sample by submitting the form without ticking any checkbox, then get incomplete samples by clicking the checkbox.

I can get incomplete samples by ticking the checkbox. I get the error while getting the complete samples.

```
if(!in_array($sample, $request->pending)){
    $tests = Session('tests');
    $createSample = Sample::create([
        'test_user_id' => $request->test_user_id,
        'received_by' => (integer)$request->received_by,
        'received_at' => $now,
        'received_name' => $request->received_name,
        'biobank' => $request->biobank,
        'order_id' => $request->order_id,
        'order_type' => $request->order_type,
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);
```

Comment: first, check if you have pending value in your request

Comment: there are none, but i need to skip the error and add the value for sample

Answer (score 2):

Its because if you don't check the checkbox, the value won't submit and hence the  `$request->pending` will be null instead of an array. You can try to check if its null and then you can do whatever you want to do with it.

```
if($request->pending){
    if(!in_array($sample, $request->pending)){
        $tests = Session('tests');
        $createSample = Sample::create([
                        'test_user_id' => $request->test_user_id,
                        'received_by' => (integer)$request->received_by,
                        'received_at' => $now,
                        'received_name' => $request->received_name,
                        'biobank' => $request->biobank,
                        'order_id' => $request->order_id,
                        'order_type' => $request->order_type,
                        'name' => $request->name,
        ]);
     }
}
```

Comment: yes, how can i still save the request even tho the request doesnt contain pending

Comment: then why are you using the if condition? just remove it.